# Python 3.4 subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

The following has worked in Python 2.7, I believe that is what I was using.  I'm currently trying to update everything to Python 3.4 and this doesn't work at all.  When I run the program it just stops and doesn't appear to run any of processes I'm asking for it to run.  I want it to run the certain process multiple times simultaneously(the subprocess updates itself to a new value so it isn't trying to do the same thing each time).  What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/ python3.4
import sys
import subprocess
procs=[]
for i in range(3):
    proc=subprocess.Popen(['python','test.py'])
    procs.append(proc)


for proc in procs:
    proc.wait()
```

I just tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import sys
import subprocess
procs=[]
for i in range(3):
    print ('hello')
    proc=subprocess.Popen(['python','test.py'])
    print ('hi')
    procs.append(proc)
    print ('goodbye')

for proc in procs:
    proc.wait()
```

It prints out the three hello, hi, goodbye fine but I wrote a quick:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
print('hello')
```

for test.py and it doesn't run that program at all.

Comment: Works fine for me with a `test.py` that just prints "hello". What is your `test.py` script doing. Perhaps add some debug code to it.

Comment: is the space after `/bin/` intentional?

Comment: add code in your main script, print things, and see where it fails.
For instance print(i) in the first for loop.

Comment: @Elazar you should make that an answer it definitely seems to be the problem assuming the script is executable and called as is.

Comment: I just tried removing the extra space and it still isn't working.  The underlying program/process is working fine...granted slowly which I'll deal with in a separate post but it is working.

Comment: Just updated the original post with the testing I've did thus far.

Comment: How are you executing the main script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is possibly due to the way you invoke python for the subprocess. When the interpreter is explicitly invoked as `python script.py` the "hashbang" is ignored and the interpreter will be `python`. Depending on your system that might be a different version of Python.

In your code `Popen(['python','test.py'])` explicitly uses `python` as the interpreter. *If* you have a different version of the interpreter, e.g. Python 2.7, as the default interpreter then that will be run, not Python 3.4 as you had hoped.

If, in turn, your subprocess script does not run properly with Python 2.7, which could well be the case if you are using `tkinter`, then you might have the problem that you have.

If this is the problem you could fix it by explicitly using the correct interpreter, e.g.

```
Popen(['python3.4','test.py'])
```

Or you could rely on the hashbang to invoke the correct interpreter:

```
Popen(['/path/to/test.py'])
```

which should work provided that the script file has executable permissions.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.  Now if I could only get the number of processes to run correctly it would be nice.  Sometimes it will run the process 3 times other times it will only run it once.  It's very inconsistent in that fashion.